# Making space available to my main partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root-filesystem

I have a cloud hosting provider, I pay for 120GB but only get 50GB and I need to make this space available on my main partition (?).

My hosting provider has not been very helpful, below is my `fdisk -l` output;

(Server runs on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
root@home:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 128.8 GB, 128849018880 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15665 cylinders, total 251658240 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e137e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      999423      498688   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          999424   104857599    51929088   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv00: 2046 MB, 2046820352 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 248 cylinders, total 3997696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv00 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01: 51.1 GB, 51124371456 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6215 cylinders, total 99852288 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

And my `df -h`;

```
root@home:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2,0G  4,0K  2,0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           395M   25M  370M   7% /run
/dev/dm-1        47G   36G  8,9G  81% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M   16K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
none            2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1       464M   66M  370M  16% /boot
```

As you can see I have 128.8GB on `/dev/sda` but I've only got 47GB available on my main hosting partition (?) I'd like to know how I would get the other 50 gigs or so onto it.

Comment: does your cloud hosting provider have technical support?

Comment: what is the output og `vgs` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Backup your VM before making any changes.**

This looks like a fairly simple issue with partitioning.  You're paying for a 120GB disk but your disk partitions only span 50GB.  Did you re-size what you are paying for?

In any case you have a couple of options.  You could create a new partition in the empty space on the disk, or you can resize the partition you have.  Fortunetly the partition you have is at the start of the disk with all the free space after it.

**Option 1: Resize**

1. You can use cfdisk for partitioning operations: `cfdisk /dev/sda`  This will give you an option to resize the partition.
2. Resize the file system with [resize2fs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/resize2fs)
3. Reboot the VM.  There are ways to avoid this step but it's generally cleaner just to reboot.

**Option 2: Add a Partition**

1. Add a partition with `cfdisk`
2. I believe cfdisk will inform the kernel of changes but if this doesn't result in a new partition being detected (`/dev/sda3`) then use [partprobe](https://linux.die.net/man/8/partprobe) to refresh: `partprobe /dev/sda`.
3. Format the partition with [mkfs.ext4](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4)
4. Mount the partition with `mount`
5. Add the partition to `/etc/fstab` (see [fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)) so that it is mounted on reboot.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm going to give it a go on Sunday, will accept answer and let you know how it goes then :)

Comment: (it went well btw, forgot to update :D)